# Android SocketClient::sendMsg(int code, const char *msg, bool addErrno) doesn't appear to do anything if the msg parameter is an empty string

Tags: android, service, daemon

I'm trying to send a response from a daemon back to my service, and all works fine if I call the `SocketClient::sendMsg(int code, const char *msg, bool addErrno)` function passed into my `FrameworkCommand::runCommand()` implementation with a non-empty `msg` string.

However, if it is empty (but not null) then my service never gets a response. There don't appear to be any exceptions thrown anywhere, just no completion of the message.

I can easily fix it in the daemon, but it would be good to know what I'm missing...